# Is this the present value of a short position on an option?

Tags: european-options, short-selling, put, present-value

Consider a European put option, whose price at time $0$ is $\Pi_0$.
Set:
$$\mathcal{L}_0=\Pi_0 - P(0,t_M)\Pi_{t_M}$$
where 0 < $t_M$ and $P(0, t_M)$ is the discount factor from time $0$ to time $t_M$.
Is that correct to state that $\mathcal{L}_0$ represents the present value of a short position on the put option? That is, at time $0$ you have a positive value equal to $\Pi_0$ and at time $t_M$ you will have to rebuy the put option at its current price (i.e. $\Pi_{t_M}$), which enters negatively (and discounted, since you have to evaluate everything at time 0) in the value of your position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close to that. Your formula represents the profit (or loss) of that position as seen from $t_0$, which is so far a stochastic term observable at expiry.

Comment: With 'that position' you mean a short position on the option, right?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, of course

Comment: Thank you a lot